# Performance issues using Elasticsearch as a time window storage

Tags: performance, indexing, elasticsearch

We are using elastic search almost as a cache, storing documents found in a time window. We continuously insert a lot of documents of different sizes and then we search in the ES using text queries combined with a date filter so the current thread does not get documents it has already seen. Something like this:

"((word1 AND word 2) OR (word3 AND word4)) AND insertedDate > 1389000"

We maintain the data in the elastic search for 30 minutes, using the TTL feature. Today we have at least 3 machines inserting new documents in bulk requests every minute for each machine and searching using queries like the one above pratically continuously.

We are having a lot of trouble indexing and retrieving these documents, we are not getting a good throughput volume of documents being indexed and returned by ES. We can't get even 200 documents indexed per second.

We believe the problem lies in the simultaneous queries, inserts and TTL deletes. We don't need to keep old data in elastic, we just need a small time window of documents indexed in elastic at a given time.
What should we do to improve our performance?

Thanks in advance

Machine type:

- An Amazon EC2 medium instance (3.7 GB of RAM)

Additional information:

- The code used to build the index is something like this:
  https://gist.github.com/dggc/6523411
- Our elasticsearch.json configuration file:
  https://gist.github.com/dggc/6523421

**EDIT**

Sorry about the long delay to give you guys some feedback. Things were kind of hectic here at our company, and I chose to wait for calmer times to give a more detailed account of how we solved our issue. We still have to do some benchmarks to measure the actual improvements, but the point is that we solved the issue :)

First of all, I believe the indexing performance issues were caused by a usage error on out part. As I told before, we used Elasticsearch as a sort of a cache, to look for documents inside a 30 minutes time window. We looked for documents in elasticsearch whose content matched some query, and whose insert date was within some range. Elastic would then return us the full document json (which had a whole lot of data, besides the indexed content). Our configuration had elastic indexing the document json field by mistake (besides the content and insertDate fields), which we believe was the main cause of the indexing performance issues.

However, we also did a number of modifications, as suggested by the answers here, which we believe also improved the performance:

- We now do not use the TTL feature, and instead use two "rolling indexes" under a common alias. When an index gets old, we create a new one, assign the alias to it, and delete the old one.
- Our application does a huge number of queries per second. We believe this hits elastic hard, and degrades the indexing performance (since we only use one node for elastic search). We were using 10 shards for the node, which caused each query we fired to elastic to be translated into 10 queries, one for each shard. Since we can discard the data in elastic at any moment (thus making changes in the number of shards not a problem to us), we just changed the number of shards to 1, greatly reducing the number of queries in our elastic node.
- We had 9 mappings in our index, and each query would be fired to a specific mapping. Of those 9 mappings, about 90% of the documents inserted went to two of those mappings. We created a separate rolling index for each of those mappings, and left the other 7 in the same index.
- Not really a modification, but we installed SPM (Scalable Performance Monitoring) from Sematext, which allowed us to closely monitor elastic search and learn important metrics, such as the number of queries fired -> sematext.com/spm/index.html

Our usage numbers are relatively small. We have about 100 documents/second arriving which have to be indexed, with peaks of 400 documents/second. As for searches, we have about 1500 searches per minute (15000 before changing the number of shards). Before those modifications, we were hitting those performance issues, but not anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TTL to time-series based indexes**

You should consider using time-series-based indexes rather than the TTL feature.  Given that you only care about the most recent 30 minute window of documents, create a new index for every 30 minutes using a date/time based naming convention: ie. docs-201309120000, docs-201309120030, docs-201309120100, docs-201309120130, etc. (Note the 30 minute increments in the naming convention.)

Using Elasticsearch's index aliasing feature (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases/), you can alias `docs` to the most recently created index so that when you are bulk indexing, you always use the alias `docs`, but they'll get written to `docs-201309120130`, for example.

When querying, you would filter on a datetime field to ensure only the most recent 30 mins of documents are returned, and you'd need to query against the 2 most recently created indexes to ensure you get your full 30 minutes of documents - you could create another alias here to point to the two indexes, or just query against the two index names directly.

With this model, you don't have the overhead of TTL usage, and you can just delete the old, unused indexes from over an hour in the past.

There are other ways to improve bulk indexing and querying speed as well, but I think removal of TTL is going to be the biggest win - plus, your indexes only have a limited amount of data to filter/query against, which should provide a nice speed boost.

**Elasticsearch settings (eg. memory, etc.)**

Here are some setting that I commonly adjust for servers running ES - http://pastebin.com/mNUGQCLY, note that it's only for a 1GB VPS, so you'll need to adjust.

**Node roles**

Looking into master vs data vs 'client' ES node types might help you as well - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/node/

**Indexing settings**

When doing bulk inserts, consider modifying the values of both `index.refresh_interval` `index.merge.policy.merge_factor` - I see that you've modified `refresh_interval` to `5s`, but consider setting it to `-1` before the bulk indexing operation, and then back to your desired interval.  Or, consider just doing a manual `_refresh` API hit after your bulk operation is done, particularly if you're *only* doing bulk inserts every minute - it's a controlled environment in that case.

With `index.merge.policy.merge_factor`, setting it to a higher value reduces the amount of segment merging ES does in the background, then back to its default after the bulk operation restores normal behaviour.  A setting of `30` is commonly recommended for bulk inserts and the default value is `10`.

Comment: We managed to improve our performance, as I explained in my edit.
We did this time-based index series you mentioned, and I think it helped our performance, even though the main issue was an error on our part.
We did not change the elastic memory settings, as it was not needed. We certainly can do that, though, as we have plenty of memory in our instance.
This option of refreshing only after bulk inserts is interesting, I will try that.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways to improve `Elasticsearch` performance:

- increase index refresh interval. Going from 1 second to 10 or 30 seconds can make a big difference in performance.
- throttle merging if it's being overly aggressive.  You can also reduce the number of concurrent merges by lowering `index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once` and `index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once_explicit`. Lowering the `index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count` can help as well

It's good to see you are using SPM.  Its URL in your EDIT was not hyperlink - it's at http://sematext.com/spm .  "`Indexing`" graphs will show how changing of the merge-related settings affects performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire up an additional ES instance and have it form a cluster with your current node. Then I would split the work between the two machines, use one for indexing and the other for querying. See how that works out for you. You might need to scale out even more for your specific usage patterns.

Comment: That would certainly improve our performance, but we were reluctant to do that, since our indexing/search numbers are kind of low. and we knew Elastic was supposed to be more powerful than that.

We managed to improve our single node performance by doing the changes I mentioned in my edit, though.